# 正規表現を使って、URL 末尾の方の情報を削除したい

Tags: php, 正規表現

http://www.amazon.co.jp/%E3%83%8E%E3%83%BC%E3%83%88%E3%83%91%E3%82%BD%E3%82%B3%E3%83%B3-EeeBook-X205TA-WHITE10-Windows10-11-6%E3%82%A4%E3%83%B3%E3%83%81%E3%83%AF%E3%82%A4%E3%83%89/dp/B015DTB87Q/ref=sr_1_1?s=computers&ie=UTF8&qid=1460353489&sr=1-1&keywords=%E3%83%91%E3%82%BD%E3%82%B3%E3%83%B3

上記のURLを下記のようにするには、どのような正規表現？を書くべきでしょうか？
URLのドメイン以外は可変の値です。
詳しい方、ご教示ください。よろしくお願いいたします。

http://www.amazon.co.jp/%E3%83%8E%E3%83%BC%E3%83%88%E3%83%91%E3%82%BD%E3%82%B3%E3%83%B3-EeeBook-X205TA-WHITE10-Windows10-11-6%E3%82%A4%E3%83%B3%E3%83%81%E3%83%AF%E3%82%A4%E3%83%89/dp/B015DTB87Q

http://www.amazon.co.jp
上記のドメイン以降で、４個目以降のスラッシュを削除したいです。

Comment: 今の質問のままでは変換規則があいまいです。まずは変換規則を決めてください。たとえば「スラッシュ `/` 以後を除去する」とか。

Comment: 追記致しました！宜しくお願い致します。

Comment: URLの不要な部分を排除したいというのが目的だと思います。で、あるならば、`http://www.amazon.co.jp/dp/B015DTB87Q`が本当に欲しい結果のような気がします。こちらを参考にしてみてはいかがですか？
 http://qiita.com/na1412/items/9bfa9c92bd32d70ec86c

Answer (score 1):

URLから4番目のスラッシュ以降を除外してマッチさせたいということであれば、

```
preg_match('#http:/(?:/[^/]+){4}#', $url, $matches);
$result = $matches[0];
// ドメインを限定するなら
// #http://www\.amazon\.co\.jp(?:/[^/]+){3}#
```

といった感じでしょうか。`http:/` から、（ドメイン名も含め）スラッシュから始まりスラッシュを含まないブロック `/[^/+]` が4回続くまでマッチします。4番目のスラッシュなしでクエリストリング等がある場合も取り除く場合は `[^/]` の代わりに `[^/?]` とするとよいかと思います。

まあAmazonに限った話なら `/dp/xxxx` を認識して細かくマッチさせてもいいですが。

```
preg_match('#https?://www\.amazon\.co\.jp/(?:[^/]+/)?dp/[A-Z0-9]+#', $url, $matches);
```

実行サンプル https://regex101.com/r/nY8dN2/1

Answer (score 0):

一発でできてなくてすいませんが・・・こんな感じかと。

```
<?php
preg_match_all('#(https?:\/\/(?:.*?\/){4})#', 'http://www.amazon.co.jp/%E3%83%8E%E3%83%BC%E3%83%88%E3%83%91%E3%82%BD%E3%82%B3%E3%83%B3-EeeBook-X205TA-WHITE10-Windows10-11-6%E3%82%A4%E3%83%B3%E3%83%81%E3%83%AF%E3%82%A4%E3%83%89/dp/B015DTB87Q/ref=sr_1_1?s=computers&ie=UTF8&qid=1460353489&sr=1-1&keywords=%E3%83%91%E3%82%BD%E3%82%B3%E3%83%B3', $m);

if (isset($m[1][0])) {
    echo rtrim($m[1][0], '\/');
}

?>
```

結果

```
http://www.amazon.co.jp/%E3%83%8E%E3%83%BC%E3%83%88%E3%83%91%E3%82%BD%E3%82%B3%E3%83%B3-EeeBook-X205TA-WHITE10-Windows10-11-6%E3%82%A4%E3%83%B3%E3%83%81%E3%83%AF%E3%82%A4%E3%83%89/dp/B015DTB87Q
```